# How to clear all data with Polymer's Firebase Element

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I'm using [firebase-element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element)

```
<firebase-document id='user'
        location="https://bar-foo.firebaseio.com/user/qo8joqjdj"
        data="{{info}}"></firebase-document>
```

And in firebase I have the following data stored:

```
bar-foo: {
    user: {
       qo8joqjdj: {  
           settings: { ... }
           profile:  { ... }
           actions:  { ... }
    }
}
```

Now, if the user clicks the button `Remove` all its data should be removed from firebase. From the [firebase-element doc](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element) there is a method called `remove`

```
this.user.remove({});
```

However, this doesn't work and I must admit it is not clear to me what exactly the argument should be. I tried different things, but none worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated ?

Comment: I believe you can empty user's data by setting it empty. Something like this: ....child('qo8joqjdj').set('')

Comment: From firebase documentation: "remove() is equivalent to calling set(null)"

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a few things here:

1. You're looking at the firebase-collection element documentation. You should refer to the [firebase-document element documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-document). remove isn't a method on firebase-document.
2. Your javascript:

   this.user.remove({})

   is not referencing an existing element or object, at least in the html you provided.
3. Using the example provided you should just need to do:

   this.info = null;

   to clear out the user's data.

Comment: You're right. There are a couple of mistakes in my post, thnx! When I set it to `null` or do `this.set('info', null)` I get an uncaught error: `Firebase.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace` So I guess the only way is: `this.set('info', {settings: {}. profile: {}, actions: {}});`

Comment: Ah ok, I was not certain if there would be firebase-document issues if you set it to null, since when using the firebase API directly that would be fine. Wondering if you couldn't just do this.info = {}? Sorry I'm being a bit too lazy to go and test myself :)

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the time you took to write this post!  With that I was able to find the solution!